# LoDash for node.js

Tags: javascript, lodash

How do I custom build lodash for node.js projects? I don't want any opera, IE, firefox based code in the custom build as i will always be using v8. Is it possible? kindly help.

Answer (score 4):

There's an existing Node package for lodash:

```
npm install lodash
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash#custom-builds):

> - Use the `exports` argument to pass comma separated names of ways to export the `LoDash` function.
>     Valid exports are *“amd”*, *“commonjs”*, *“global”*, *“node”*, and *“none”*.
>
>   `lodash exports=amd,commonjs,node`
>     `lodash exports="amd, commonjs, node"`

More on generating custom builds [here](https://vimeo.com/44154601).

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific Node package: [lodash-node](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-node)

Comment: This is deprecated after lodash 3.0; The node modules are now in the `lodash` package.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install `npm install --save lodash`

Use wherever needed with with

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const array = [1];
const other = _.concat(array, 2, [3], [[4]]);
```